# How to implement Typeahead in angular ui-grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am trying to implement typeahead in editable cell of ui-grid.problem is, when i selected one of the option of typeahead,the value does not reflected in the cell.

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SoZDlH8YUKHTTLdq9Maa?p=preview)

This is my partial code:

```
$scope.template2='<div class=""><input style="border: none;" type="text" ' +
                                        'class="typeaheadcontrol"' +
                                        'ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index"'+
                                        'ng-model="COL_FIELD"' +
                                        'data-typeahead="state.name as state.name for state in grid.appScope.states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" ' +
                                        'data-typeahead-editable ="false"' +
                                         'ui-grid-editor'+
                                        '/></div> '
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        rowTemplate: rowTemplate(),
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
          { name: 'name' },

          { name: 'cumulativeWidgets',editDropdownValueLabel:'name', field: 'widgets', cellFilter: 'formatStatus',
          editableCellTemplate: $scope.template2,
          cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"  ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.openAttributes(rowRenderIndex)" title="TOOLTIP">{{COL_FIELD }}</div>',
          }
        ]
      };
```

i don't know why selected value is not reflected in view(cell).Is there any issue with my code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add editableCellTemplate as below

```
editableCellTemplate :'<div><form name="inputForm"><input  type="INPUT_TYPE"  ng-model="row.entity.name" typeahead="state for state in grid.appScope.states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" ></form></div>'
```

You can use uiGridEditor  (ui-grid-editor) or other directive so as to provide `BEGIN_CELL_EDIT, CANCEL_CELL_EDIT and END_CELL_EDIT` events. This will hide the textbox as well after edit.

[Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/o2LPpkXLeMfQ3wdtFnGT?p=preview) for plnkr example

Comment: Add ui-grid-editor or other directive to add events and close the textbox

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question but I have been fighting ui-grid and typeahead all morning so... I'm going to post what worked out for me.

I was having major issues with typeahead only working a few times.  I solved it, hopefully, by adding a unique ID to anything with a dropdown.  My cell template turned into this:

```
'<div><input id="{{row.entity.$$hashKey}}" type="text" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ' +
' typeahead-on-select="grid.appScope.typeaheadSelected(grid, row, $item)" ng-class="{edited: grid.isEdited(row, col)}" ' +
'ng-change="grid.appScope.typeaheadSelected(grid)" ' +
'typeahead="state for state in grid.appScope.primaryKeyValues.{{col.colDef.name}} | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"></div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this hasn't been answered, so here is what I did to solve it. First I did the whole editableCellTemplate with the typeahead as suggested above. Which worked but I noticed that the ui-grid-editor directive takes over the key handling events, so when the typeahead shows, you can't arrow down the list or select an item from the list. If you remove the ui-grid-editor directive from the editableCellTemplate string then the input element remains after you lose focus, so I looked in the UI-grid source and found the directive called uiGridEditor and noticed that commenting out the key event handlers allows the typeahead to use the key events as well as using the ui-grid after edit focus api. We use a minified version of ui-grid, and didn't want to alter the source, so I then copied the uiGridEditor directive from the source and created my own directive called uiGridEditorExtended, I then removed the key event handler, and changed the directive name in the editbleCellTemplate to ui-grid-editor-extended so that it uses mine instead of the one in the ui-grid. Now it shows the typeahead, allows the keys to be used by typeahead and allows the ui-grid to recognize an off focus.

Comment: can you share a plnkr?